# How can i filter my search by an boolean atrribute?

Tags: reactjs, instantsearch

How can i filter the hits? i have this structure: the Hit have an attribute 'like' its a boolean, i want to show only the Hits with `like===true`

```
 <Configure hitsPerPage={100} />
   <Grid >
     <Grid >
       <Hits hitComponent={Hit} />
     </Grid>
   </Grid>
```

in witch part can i use filter?

This is my configuration to search, by mean this documentation https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/configure/react/

```
<InstantSearch
        searchClient={vclient}
        indexName={`myVarClient`}
      >
```

i was trying with `<Configure  filters="category:secure" hitsPerPage={100} />` its worked but when i try with the bool attribute this dont work what is the wrong?

i tried with  but dont worked, while with this  worked good i need with the boolean like attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should configurate from the dashboard

> Go to your dashboard and select your index. Click the Configuration
> tab. Under the Filtering and Faceting category, click on Facets. In
> the Attributes for faceting section, click on Add an Attribute and
> select the attribute you wish to declare for faceting. For each
> attribute, click the dropdown on the right and set them as
> “searchable”, “filter only” or “not searchable”. Don’t forget to save
> your changes
> this info is from: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/faceting/how-to/declaring-attributes-for-faceting/

or from its api client:

```
index.setSettings({
  attributesForFaceting: [
    'like',
  ]
}).then(() => {
  // done
});
```

more info: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/attributesForFaceting/#examples

> Modifiers:# filterOnly: Defines an attribute as filterable only and
> not facetable.
>
> If you only need the filtering feature, you can take advantage of
> filterOnly which will reduce the index size and improve the speed of
> the search.
>
> You cannot define an attribute as both ‘filterOnly’ and ‘searchable’.
> The following therefore is not doable:
> filterOnly(searchable(attributeName)).
>
> searchable: Defines an attribute as searchable.

then this will work

```
<Configure  filters="like:true" hitsPerPage={100} />
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Configure`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/configure/react/) widget is the way to go for this use case. You have to ensure that the attribute provided is in the list of [`attributesForFaceting`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/attributesForFaceting/) otherwise the filter won't work. Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-instantsearch-boolean-filter-with-configure-0o3yo?file=/src/App.js) that uses the field `free_shipping` which is a boolean attribute.

```
<InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName="instant_search">
  <Configure filters="free_shipping:true" />
</InstantSearch>
```